# Flutter bloc - Show snackbar on state change

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am trying to log in with Google. When googleSignInAccount I yield new state with PlatformExecption. Now, How can I access that value in order to do some changes.

```
try{
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();

    if(googleSignInAccount == null){
     yield GoogleLoginErrorState(error: PlatformException(code: 'user-cancel'));
    }
}
```

my state.dart

```
class GoogleLoginErrorState extends GoogleLoginState {
  final PlatformException error;
  GoogleLoginErrorState({this.error});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [error];
}
```

my BlocBuilder

```
if (state == GoogleLoginErrorState()) {

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bloc builder,

```dart
if (state is GoogleLoginErrorState) {

}
```

This checks if the `state` data type is `GoogleLoginErrorState`

And use the `state`

```dart
Text(state.error.code)
```

Comment: The question asks for snackbar, and using like this it won't be able to raise a snackbar

Answer (score 4):

For side effects such as showing snackbars / dialogs or navigating to another screen, you have to use `BlocListener`, something like this:

```dart
  BlocListener<YourGoogleSigninBloc, YourGoogleSigninState>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      if(state is GoogleLoginErrorState){
        // show snackbar here
      }
    },
    child: YourWidget(),
  )
```

you can also use `BlocConsumer` instead of nesting `BlocListener`s and `BlocBuilder`s like this:

```dart
BlocConsumer<YourGoogleSigninBloc, YourGoogleSigninState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if(state is GoogleLoginErrorState){
        // show snackbar here
    }
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    return YourWidget();
  },
)
```